# Vscode API - Custom View Container Icon

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm wanting to use an SVG for the viewcontainer part of my VS Code extension.

I've been given some PNG files to use, but unfortunately:

When just using 32x32 PNG files, the icons always show up as a blank white square in the activity bar, and if used as SVG the images don't scale properly to the container in the activity bar.

It's as though they are "zoomed in" on if using the SVG versions.

Anyone have tips or tricks to suggest working around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the open tag of the `debug.svg` icon used in the action bar

```
<svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

Do you have a `viewbox` set?

Comment: It looks like in my case that I do not. I was using a port of potrace linked on an old SO post. http://kilobtye.github.io/potrace/ that appears only to generate id, version, width, height, xmlns, path, stroke, fill, and full-rule. Would I manually be able to specify a viewBox with pixels?

Comment: I also tried adding in the viewbox property on the tag, and left it as "". I can preview the image in VS Code with SVG Viewer extension, but still shows up blank in the activity bar :*(

Comment: set the viewbox to the same size of the width and height, most likely an empty viewbox equals no-viewbox

Comment: thanks for the tips. I was able to end up fiddling with the values in `viewbox` along with the height and width settings, eventually got it to work. Much appreciated!